# MVS SQL Server Update

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i am using microsoft visual studio 2010 professional for my project and involves using database,last summer it was working perfectly,on testing my project now i get an error saying the SQL Server needs to be updated, can i please get help on how to update it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to SQL Server and Visual Studio are done through Windows Updates.

Run it and it will tell you what updates you need to install.

Comment: @Jide, no problem. Don't forget that if the answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted.